# AWS Lamda function got deleted. Not able to retrieve

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

I am using serverless framework in c# to execute queries in athena. AWS Lamda function deleted automatically. When i am trying to deploy it, it's not happening.

`sls deploy --stage dev`     -- To deploy function
`sls remove --stage dev`     -- To remove function
When i tried to redeploy it, it's giving error like below:

[image]

As they have mentioned in above screenshot, for more error output i have browsed the link: which shows stack detail. I have attached it below

Refer this image:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

serverless.yml

```
 # Welcome to Serverless!
#
# This file is the main config file for your service.
# It's very minimal at this point and uses default values.
# You can always add more config options for more control.
# We've included some commented out config examples here.
# Just uncomment any of them to get that config option.
#
# For full config options, check the docs:
#    docs.serverless.com
#
# Happy Coding!

service: management-athena

custom:
  defaultStage: dev
  currentStage: ${opt:stage, self:custom.defaultStage} # 'dev' is default unless overriden by --stage flag

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: dotnetcore2.1
  stage: ${self:custom.currentStage}
  role: arn:aws:iam::***********:role/service-role/nexus_labmda_schema_partition  # must validly reference a role defined in your account
  timeout: 300
  environment: # Service wide environment variables
    DATABASE_NAME: ${file(./config/config.${self:custom.currentStage}.json):DATABASE_NAME}
    TABLE_NAME: ${file(./config/config.${self:custom.currentStage}.json):TABLE_NAME}
    S3_PATH: ${file(./config/config.${self:custom.currentStage}.json):S3_PATH}
    MAX_SITE_TO_BE_PROCESSED: ${file(./config/config.${self:custom.currentStage}.json):MAX_SITE_TO_BE_PROCESSED}

package:
  artifact: bin/release/netcoreapp2.1/deploy-package.zip

functions:
  delete_partition:
    handler: CsharpHandlers::AwsAthena.AthenaHandler::DeletePartition
    description: Lambda function which runs at specified interval to delete athena partitions
    # The `events` block defines how to trigger the AthenaHandler.DeletePartition code
    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: cron(0 8 * * ? *) #triggered every day at 3:00 AM EST.Provided time is in UTC. So 3 A.M EST is 8 A.M UTC
          enabled: true
```

Comment: What details exist in `View failure event details`? What is `DeleteUnderscorePartitionLogGroup`? Adding your yaml script might help in understanding the problem you are having.

Comment: @ASR I have added .yml

Comment: Not sure if you have seen this - https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/5057

Comment: I have already tried it. Since my current serverless version is 1.37 i tried to downgrade it to 1.27.3. It's not installing any other version except 1.37

Comment: I could upgrade serverless version to 1.37.1 But, even after that same issue i am facing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out the solution! 
 Sometimes we won't be able to deploy lamda functions because of many reasons. as @ASR mentioned in comments, there might serverless framework's version issues. But in my case, that didn't solve. Just try deleting the logs group of your function from the cloud watch.

Go to aws -> expand services -> select CloudWatch -> select Logs -> search for your log group  select it and delete it. Let's say if your function name is **my_function** then your log group name will be something like this: **aws/lamda/my_function**
Then just deploy your lamda function. 
I am posting this thinking that it helps someone...! Please correct me if i am wrong.